# Difference between 内容, 明細 and 詳細

Tags: word-usage, pragmatics

According to JMDict 内容, 明細 and 詳細 meaning is [details](http://tangorin.com/general/%E5%86%85%E5%AE%B9%20%E6%98%8E%E7%B4%B0%E3%80%80%E8%A9%B3%E7%B4%B0). I see these 熟語 at the same time on banks websites. What are the nuances of their usage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### [内容]{ないよう}

- The contents, part of something
- Physically inside of something
- Near to `[中身]{なかみ}`, which means more physical *content*

### [明細]{めいさい}

- Detailed document of something like bank accounts
- Detailed statement

It appears often in topics and documents related to money.

Example:

> [給与明細]{きゅうよめいさい} = payslip

It can also be an adjective but it's not a common usage.

### [詳細]{しょうさい}

- Nearly most common word which means `detail`, in written language
- `詳細な` and `[詳]{くわ}しい` are mostly identical

The combination `詳細な内容` is possible like

> 詳細な内容を[教]{おし}えてください。
>
> Please tell me the detailed contents.